# First window program : Not able to see output

Tags: visual-c++

Well , it may sound silly but I have made first Windows program which goes as:

```
#include<windows.h>
int_stdcall WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,               
                     LPSTR IpszCmdline,                 
                     int nCmdShow) 
{
    MessageBox(0, "Hello!", "Title", MB_OK); 
    return 0; 
}
```

when I am running it , it runs but output window doesn't show. I mean I am not seeing any window with "Title" on title bar and "Hello" and OK. What is the solution?

Comment: Is that a typo? It should be `int __stdcall WinMain` or  `int APIENTRY WinMain`

Comment: I DIDN'T GET IT. EVEN IF I CORRECT IT BY TWO UNDERSCORES , HOW DOES IT MATTER.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You can type in `banana fish WinMain(eggs)` and you can ignore the compiler error messages. I am giving up on you.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the line

```
int_stdcall WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance,   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                     LPSTR IpszCmdline, int nCmdShow)
```

with the following code:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
```

because "int_stdcall" is incorrect.

Also, in the MessageBox function, you should write

```
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hello!"), TEXT("Title"), MB_OK);
```